# Can anyone help in drawing this kind of graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, graphs

Can anyone help in drawing the graph of the kind shown in figure with edge intersections? I struggled with `pstricks` and started to learn `tikz` but not able to do it. Kindly help as am not getting how to use points or co-ordinates so that I can draw a dashed edge intersecting already existing edge. Any package is ok.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Where is your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: See the examples on doing intersections in tikz at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/intersections/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started. Using only `tikz`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=6mm}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (a) {A};
    \node[mynode,below left=2cm and 2cm of a] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below right=2cm and 2cm of c] (f) {F};
    \node[mynode,right=3cm of a] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below right=2cm and 2cm of b] (d) {D};
    \node[mynode,below left=2cm and 2cm of d] (e) {E};
    %% lines
    \draw[thick] (a) -- node[above left]{a} (c);
    \draw[thick] (c) -- node[below left]{c} (f);
    \draw[thick] (a) -- node[above right]{e} node[below left]{g} (e);
    \draw[thick] (b) -- node[above=3mm]{i} (d)node[pos=0.5,sloped](i){};
    \draw[thick] (d) -- node[above left]{h} (e);
    \draw[dashed,thick,shorten >= 2cm,shorten <= -2cm] (i.north) -- (i.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \medskip
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (a) {A};
    \node[mynode,below left=2cm and 2cm of a] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below right=2cm and 2cm of c] (f) {F};
    \node[mynode,right=3cm of a] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below right=2cm and 2cm of b] (d) {D};
    \node[mynode,below left=2cm and 2cm of d] (e) {E};
    %% lines
    \draw[thick] (a) -- node[above left]{a} (c);
    \draw[thick] (c) -- node[below left]{c} (f);
    \draw[thick] (a) -- node[above right]{e} node[below left]{g} (e);
    \draw[thick] (b) -- node[above right]{i} (d);
    \draw[thick] (d) -- node[above=3mm]{h} (e)node[pos=0.5,sloped](i){};
    \draw[dashed,thick,shorten >= 2cm,shorten <= -2cm] (i.north) -- (i.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]